# Grouping rows of DataFrame based on time/location features quickly

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a pandas DataFrame with rows corresponding to events and columns corresponding to the time, latitude, and longitude of those events. It looks a bit like this:

```
     time                      latitude   longitude
0    1994-03-01 03:49:00.830    49.096     32.617 . . .
1    1994-10-04 11:41:28.080    10.964    133.891 . . .
2    1995-06-02 03:38:03.890    19.803    -52.799 . . .
3    1995-08-21 19:17:15.300   -19.851   -175.043 . . .
.
.
.
```

What I'm trying to do is group the events in this dataset so that an event is grouped with every event within a certain time and a certain distance, `timedif` and `spacedif`.

For example, suppose `timedif` is 1 year (ignoring the other variable), then I want a group for event 0 above, which contains event 1 but not event 2, and event 1 should not receive a group because it is in group 0. There is then a second group for event 2, containing 3, etc.

What I am currently trying is very inefficient:

```
dfbuild = dfbuild.append({'head index': 0, 'sub index': [] },ignore_index = True)
for i in dfog.index:
    for j in dfbuild.index:
        if(timecomp(dfog.loc[dfbuild.loc[j]['head index']]['time'],dfog.loc[i]['time']) < timedif ):
            if(geopy.distance.distance( (dfog.loc[i]['latitude'],dfog.loc[i]['longitude']),(dfog.loc[dfbuild.loc[j]['head index']]['latitude'],dfog.loc[dfbuild.loc[j]['head index']]['longitude']) ).km < spacedif ):
                head = j
                break
    if(head == -1):
        dfbuild = dfbuild.append({'head index': i, 'sub index': [] },ignore_index = True)
    else:
        dfbuild.loc[head]['sub index'].append(i)
    head = -1
```

(timecomp just uses datetime to convert the strings to a datetime then subtracts them; I'm using the geopy.distance.distance() function to get the distances between latitudes and longitudes)

I know this is pretty ugly and I think I'm using `.loc` wrong, but it works; I end up with a DataFrame with two columns, one with the `head index` values, and one with all the corresponding `sub index` values. However it is incredibly slow, and as the dataset gets larger it slows down exponentially.

What can I do to speed it up? I'm also not attached to doing it this way, so if I should completely scrap it and go about it differently, that's an option.

Note that the rows in the dataset are in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use geopandas http://geopandas.org
For time grouping use for example:

```
times = pd.to_datetime(dfbuild.time)
dfbuild.groupby([times.hour, times.minute]).count()
```